# Find shape of minimum resistance between two points given a fixed volume of conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, optimization

I am given a homogenous volume $F$ of isotropic conductor with resistivity $\rho$. I need to allow current to flow from Point A to B which are a distance $L$ away from each other. I can shape the conductor anyway I like.

Let's assume the conductor lies along the $x$-axis. We can assume the conductor has some longish shape and $L \gg \sqrt{A(x)} , \forall x $ where $A(x)$ is the cross-sectional area at point $x$ along the line joining A and B.

What is the shape of the conductor with minimal resistance i.e. what function $A(x)$ will give minimize resistance?
**Update**: Assume contact areas will be as big as needed - meaning contact area at $x=0$ will be $A(x=0)$ and at $x=L$ will be $A(x=L)$.

I have shown my own answer below, but I'm not happy with it. Primarily because it starts off with assuming the optimum shape (cylinder?). Further, it doesn't help with a different case where, say, there are multiple sources and sinks for current. I'm looking for a more general method.

Answer (score 0):

I got one (unsatisfactory) way of solving it, which is basically the intuition that because $R=\frac{\rho l}{A}$, any reduction in cross-sectional area anywhere (say at $x=k$) cannot be compensated by merely adding that area elsewhere (say at $x=m > k$) — instead I have to scale the area at $m$ by the ratio I decreased it at $k$. Further intuition leads me to the obvious idea that a cylinder has to hence yield minimal resistance.

Nevertheless, with this intuition, I set out to prove below that the cylinder is indeed optimal.

A cylinder implies $A(x)$ is a constant, value equal to $\frac{F}{L}$. The resistance would then be $R=\frac{\rho L}{F/L} = \frac{\rho L^2}{F}$. I model the cylinder in the form of thin slices with area $A(x)$ and length $dx$.

I now reduce the cross-sectional area by $\Delta A$ between $k<x<(k+\Delta x)$. I now have spare conducting material of volume $\Delta A \Delta x$, which I will deposit between $m<x<(m+\Delta x)$, $m>k$. So between $k$ and $k+\Delta x$ the cross-sectional area is $A-\Delta A$, and between $m$ and $m+\Delta x$ the cross-sectional area is $A+\Delta A$.

Resistance is given by $$R=\int\limits_0^L\frac{\rho\,dx}{A(x)}$$
$$ =
\int\limits_{0}^{k}\frac{\rho\,dx}{F/L} +
\int\limits_{k}^{k+\Delta x}\frac{\rho\,dx}{F/L - \Delta A} +
\int\limits_{k+\Delta x}^{m}\frac{\rho\,dx}{F/L} +
\int\limits_{m}^{m+\Delta x}\frac{\rho\,dx}{F/L + \Delta A} +
\int\limits_{m+\Delta x}^L\frac{\rho\,dx}{F/L}
$$
$$
= 
\frac{\rho L}{F}
\left(
\int\limits_{0}^{k}dx +
\int\limits_{k+\Delta x}^{m} dx +
\int\limits_{m+\Delta x}^L dx
\right)
+ 
\rho L
\left(
\int\limits_{k}^{k+\Delta x}\frac{dx}{F - L\Delta A} +
\int\limits_{m}^{m+\Delta x}\frac{dx}{F + L\Delta A}
\right)
$$
$$
=\frac{\rho L}{F} [ (k - 0) + (m - (k + \Delta x)) + (L - (m - \Delta x))]
+ \rho L \left[
\frac{k+ \Delta x - k}{F - L\Delta A} + \frac{m + \Delta x - m}{F + L\Delta A}
\right]
$$
$$
=
\frac{\rho L}{F} (L-2\Delta x) + 
\rho L \left[\frac{\Delta x}{F - L\Delta A} + \frac{\Delta x}{F + L\Delta A}\right]
$$
$$
=
\frac{\rho L^2}{F} + \rho L \left[\frac{\Delta x}{F - L\Delta A} - \frac{2 \Delta x}{F} + \frac{\Delta x}{F + L\Delta A}\right]
$$
Since we know $\frac{\rho L^2}{F}$ is the original resistance of the cylinder, we need to show that the remainder term $R_{rem}$ is positive.
$$
R_{rem} = \rho L \Delta x \left[\frac{1}{F - L\Delta A} - \frac{1}{F} - \frac{1}{F} + \frac{1}{F + L\Delta A}\right]
$$
$$
=\rho L \Delta x \left[ \frac{F-F+L\Delta A}{F(F-L\Delta A)} - \frac{F + L\Delta A - F}{F(F+L\Delta A)}
\right]
$$
$$
=\frac{\rho L^2 \Delta x \Delta A}{F} \left[ \frac{1}{F-L\Delta A} - \frac{1}{F+L\Delta A}
\right]
$$
Since $F>L\Delta A$, that implies $F-L\Delta A > 0$. Also,
$$\frac{1}{F-L\Delta A} > \frac{1}{F+L\Delta A}$$

Therefore $R_{rem}>0$, which applied for any $0<k<m<L$ and any $\Delta x > 0$ and $\Delta A > 0$.

Therefore the cylinder is the shape with the lowest resistance $R = \frac{\rho L^2}{F}$. Any change in the shape only increases the resistance.

Answer (score 0):

This makes mathematically no sense, point contacts to a solid medium have infinite resistance because of the $1/r$ current density, spreading out from such a point. It has a singularity. Formulated like this you cannot do rigorous mathematics.

Maybe you can change the points to circles, or disks on each side. Then at least a finite result for $R$ is possible and there must be a rigorously defined minimum! Still, if the disks are small in size they will dominate the total $R$ which would result in a shape more or less like this:

[image: shape]

to minimize the spreading resistance. This means that the simplest solution, just trying an ellipsoid and putting it into the Euler-Lagrange equation to see if it is an extremum, will probably not work...

Comment: You're right, I didn't specify contact resistances, but can it not be rescued by having contact areas be $A_{c1}=A(x=0)$ and $A_{c2}=A(x=L)$ ??

Comment: You then prohibit the shape that I've drawn (where The object's area $A(x=0)$ clearly extends beyound the area of the contact disk $A$.   
But that shape will not be needed if your contact disks automatically "adapt" to the area around them, so that's fine.

Comment: Yeah, it will not be needed was my hope... I'm now looking for a better way to prove the optimality of cylinder, or a counterexample.

Comment: The cylinder is optimal if the contact disks fit exactly on its ends, making them a bit smaller or larger would force us to deform the cylinder. And after that, using $R=\int\limits_0^L\frac{\rho\,dx}{A(x)}$ is only an approximation, because it is not valid for all possible 3D shapes.